# Is the equals operator reducable to basic logic and set theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Usually, an equivalence relation ($=$) is defined as having the following three properties:

- Reflexivity. $\forall x, x = x$
- Symmetry. $\forall x, y \text{  }$   $y = x$ if and only if $y = x$
- Transitivity. $\forall x, y, z, \text{     } x = y$ and $y = z \implies x = z$

In (first-order logic + equality), authors often act as if the equality operator is a new thing not expressible in first order logic alone.

Can we define an equals sign ($=$) purely in terms of set theory?

Can we define an equivalence relation in such a way that reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity are all theorems, instead of definitions or axioms?

Comment: In first-order set theory, set equality and extesionality can be defined as follows: Def. $\forall x (A \in x \leftrightarrow B \in x) \to (A=B)$ and Ax. $(A \subseteq B) \land (B \subseteq A) \to (A=B)$

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that $=$ is already part of basic logic.

So, $=$ acts like a predicate in terms of inductively defining well-formed formulas, but in ordinary first-order logic it is a *logical* symbol. This means that its semantics are given to us by the logic itself. The alternative is a non-logical symbol, which includes predicates of positive arity $P, Q \cdots$, functions of positive arity $f, g, \cdots$ and constants $c, d, \cdots$ (also sometimes symbols like $0$ and $1$).

If we talk about first-order logic without equality and consider structures where $=$ is given an interpretation just like any other non-logical predicate, then one has to introduce the notion of a [*normal model*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_logic_without_equality) if you want to do things like talk about the cardinality of a model. In a normal model, the parts of the partition of the domain associated with $=$ are all singletons. Another way of looking at it is that we can't really escape making $=$ special in some way. In the equality-less setting, though, we would still have to insist that $=$ is an equivalence relation in order to mod out by it later and its status as an equivalence relation would be given to us by axioms.

That being said, the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) gives you a very strong relationship between $\in$ and $=$, specifically:

$$ \forall a \mathop. \forall e \mathop. (\forall i \mathop. a \in i \leftrightarrow e \in i) \to a = e $$

This axiom should be read as a *constraint on what $\in$ is allowed to do* rather than a *definition for equality*.

Comment: I wish I had explained the motivation behind my question. There are many many different equality relations. I do not like the usual definition of things like "surjective function." A function $F$ from $A$ to $B$ is ***surjective*** if and only if $\forall y \in B \exists x \in A$ such that $F(x) = y$. the problem is that using an equal sign $=$ insinuates that we have already defined an equality relation on set $A$. In many cases, it is not clear what makes one element set A equal to another.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon, this is the point I was trying to make is that $=$ is not like any other predicate. It really is part of the logic. When you pick a semantics, the raw material that that semantics is built out of is set theory, and any two sets are the same set or they are not. If you choose to do things slightly differently and make $=$ an equivalence relation, then discussing properties of models will require you to mod out by that equivalence relation anyway, so you might as well just insist that $=$ really is equality.

Comment: If you are willing to consider more complicated logics than FOL like [monadic second order logic (MSO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_second-order_logic), then you can define equality $x \neq y$ as $\exists P \mathop. P(x) \land \lnot P(y)$. This gives you equality in the standard semantics of second-order logic, but gives you a congruence relation that might not be equality in the Henkin semantics. You can come up with settings in which equality is non-primitive, but in FOL there isn't really anything you can use to define it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is one attempt:

> Let $A$ be a set.
>
> We say that $P$ is a predicate on $A \>$ if and only if $\> P$ is a subset of $A \times \{true, false\}$ such that both of the following statements are true:
>
> - For all $x \in A$ there exists $y \in \{true, false\}$ such that $(x, y) \in P$
> - For all $x \in A$, $(x, true) \in P$ if and only if $(x, false) ∉ P$.
>
> Let $PS$ be the set of all predicates on $A$.
>
> For any $x, y \in A$ we say that $x = y$ if and only if for every predicate $P \in PS$, $(x, true) \in P$ if and only if $(y, true) \in P$.